# What is it called when every object of a category is the quotient object of some free object?

Tags: category-theory

For example, every group is the quotient of a free group. Is there a name for this property in a general category, or does this property necessarily follow from the universal property of free objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "quotient object," but broadly speaking, this says that the free object on one element is some kind of [generator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator) of the category, for various values of "generator" (see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/generators/) for a lengthy discussion of what "generator" can mean).

First, note that to define "free object" you need more than just the structure of a category. What you need is really a [concrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category): a category equipped with a forgetful functor $U : C \to \text{Set}$. You can then define free objects, if they exist, using a left adjoint $F : \text{Set} \to C$ of this functor (if it exists).

One thing you might mean by "quotient" is "epimorphism." So you might ask that every object admits an epimorphism from a free object. If $C$ has all coproducts, this is equivalent to the condition that the free object $F(1)$ on one element is a generator in the usual sense, namely that $\text{Hom}(F(1), -) \cong U(-)$ is faithful (which in our setup is always true, since we assumed that $U$ is faithful).

But epimorphisms don't always behave like quotients. For example, in commutative rings, $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism, but it seems strange to think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$. A better way to say "quotient" is [regular epimorphism](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/regular-and-effective-monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/), and this corresponds to $F(1)$ being a generator in a stronger sense.

Comment: So do all objects of [algebraic categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category) admit a regular epimorphism from a free object?

Comment: @Sintrastes: not sure, but it's true for categories monadic over $\text{Set}$, which includes all familiar examples (groups, rings, modules) and even some more exotic examples like compact Hausdorff spaces.